# (r programming) How can I trim the start and end of a string in a dataframe in r, while preserving the middle?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe from a chess game that contains the following data:

```
>View(game_summary_df)

   white_player      black_player           result       white_elo       black_elo
1 [White Gyc12] [Black SuperCarp] [Result 1/2-1/2] [WhiteElo 1355] [BlackElo 1243]
```

I would like to clean up the data by removing, for instance, "[White " and "]" from the white_player column, leaving only "Gyc12".

I am able to accomplish this using two separate str_replace commands:

```
> str_replace(game_summary_df[1,1], "\\[White ", "")
> str_replace(game_summary_df[1,1], "\\]", "")
```

Is there a way to combine this into one str_replace command? Something like the opposite of .+? to place in the middle is my thought.

Comment: @onyambu ... but that doesn't generalize well to cleanup the other columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP talked of cleaning it from the `white_player` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this cleanup in a single function call, you may use `gsub()` with an alternation.  For example:

```
white_player <- "[White Gyc12]"
output <- gsub("^\\[\\w+\\s+|\\]$", "", white_player)
output

[1] "Gyc12"
```

Answer (score 1):

`game_summary_df[1,1] %>% str_extract((?<=White ).*(?=\\]))`